# Is there an API to get StreamsMetadata from Zookeeper/Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-streams

The info I am looking for is the `HostInfo` of the streams instance that holds the stored key, But I would like to do it before I get to the Streams instance. Note : the instances will be running.

```
  //this is how you do it with the Kafka Streams API
  StreamsMetadata metadata = streams.metadataForKey(storeName, key, new StringSerializer());
  HostInfo info metadata.hostInfo()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. `StreamsMetadata` on only available at runtime and not stored anywhere.

Comment: Well the instances will be running it's just I would like to get it from a different source than a Streams instance, when you say it's not stored anywhere? Then how does the current instance get the info from other instances?

Comment: This information is exchanges during rebalance. It's only hold in-memory.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, looks like I need to do the recommended way and get host info local on one instance then do a RPC request to the second instance to get the key with the host info from the above code. But this is an extra request I would like to eliminate.

Comment: You can still cache the information, to avoid double request later on. We don't store this information, because it might change at any point in time.